# Multi CURL C++ Continually supply new handlers when ready

Tags: c++, curl

I am using the CURL Multi API in C++.

At the moment I cap the number of handlers I give it to at 5, so that I have to wait until they are all done until I can supply another 5 handlers.

I want to be able to detect when a handler has completed, process the data, then generate the next handler to put in the new space.

Is it possible to pass handlers to the Multi API whilst it is running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass handlers to the Multi API whilst it is running?

Yes.

As soon as `curl_multi_info_read` returns a message with `CURLMSG_DONE` flag you can:

1. retrieve the corresponding easy handle via `msg->easy_handle`
2. check the transfer is OK and do what you want with the response,
3. remove this easy handle with `curl_multi_remove_handle`

Then you can add another handle to your multi handle with `curl_multi_add_handle`.

Most of the time the [best way to proceed](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html#Persistence) is to perform a `curl_easy_reset` on the easy handle, before adding it again:

```
  curl_multi_remove_handle(multi_handle, easy_handle);
  curl_easy_reset(easy_handle);
  // here re-configure your handle for the next transfer (CURLOPT_URL, etc)
  // ...
  curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, easy_handle);
```